# How to perform a variable expansion of the string variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, debugging, environment-variables

I am writing a simple bash debugging tool, `log_next_line`. The intended behavior is when the `log` variable is defined it reads next line of the script, expand variables on it, writes it to the file specified by `$log`, executes the command, and capture its output to the same log.

I have the problem with the variable expansion. Suppose I have a line of bash code in variable `$line`. How to expand the strings in it without executing any external programs, and without executing pipes (which is dangerous)?

The simple `line=$("echo $line")` doesn't work at all. 
When I try `line=$(bash -c "echo $line")` I have better luck, but then I need to export ALL bash variables to the spawned bash (which I have no idea how to do). And calling the external program for it seems like a overkill; besides the bash will execute the pipes and external programs, if e.g. `line="echo $(rm -r /)"`.

Is there any way to do the variable expansion that will not involve writing a Bash parser from scratch ;-) ? I only need it to work under Linux (Ubuntu >= 14.04 to be precise).

For a full picture I include the prototype of the function:

```
function log_next_line()
{
    if [ -n "$log" ]; then
        file=${BASH_SOURCE[1]##*/}  #Takes path to the file, from where the function is called
        linenr=$((${BASH_LINENO[0]} + 1 )) #Line number
        line=`sed "${linenr}q;d" $file` #Reads this line number from the source file
        line=$("echo $line") #DOESN'T WORK. I want it to do a variable expansion
        echo "\$ $line" >>$log #Writes the variable-expanded line to the log
        $line >>$log 2>>$log #Executes the line and 
        exitstatus=$?
        if [ "$exitstatus" -ne "0" ]; then
            echo "## Exit status: $exitstatus" >>$log
        fi
        echo >>$log
        BASH_LINENO[0]=$((BASH_LINENO[0] + 1)) #Skips executing of the next line, since we have already executed it (and captured its output)
        if [ "$exitstatus" -ne "0" ]; then
            exit $exitstatus
        fi
    fi
}
```

And the simple script that can be used as a test case

```
#!/bin/bash

log=mylog.log

. ./log_next_line.sh

rm mylog.log

a=4
b=example
x=a

log_next_line
echo $x
log_next_line
echo ${!b}
log_next_line
touch ${!b}.txt > /dev/null
log_next_line
touch ${!x}.txt
log_next_line
if [ (( ${#a} - 6  )) -gt 10 ]; then echo "Too long string";fi
log_next_line
echo "\$a and \$x"|tee file.txt
```

---

unit tests:

if `x=a`, `a="example"` then I want the following expansions:

1. `echo $x` should be `echo a`.
2. `echo ${!b}` should be `echo example`
3. `touch ${!b}.txt>/dev/null` should be `touch example.txt>/dev/null`
4. `if [ (( ${#a} - 6  )) -gt 10 ]; then echo "Too long string";fi` should be `if [ 1 -gt 10 ]; then echo "Too long string";fi`
5. `echo "\$a and \$x"|tee file.txt` should be `echo "\$a and \$x"|tee file.txt"`

---

This question is a generalization of the https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131150/bash-is-it-safe-to-eval-bash-command . The answers given there don't pass all my test cases.

Comment: I assume that you're familiar with `-x` shell option? It does exactly what you're trying to implement but generally without need to modify sources.

Comment: Why are you doing `line=sed "${linenr}q;d" $file`? That looks like an expansion nightmare. Why not `line=$( sed -n ${linenr}p "$file" )`. That will fetch `$linenr` from `$file` without embedding an end of line within double-quotes, which, even if it works, is a trainwreck.

Answer (score 1):

the function could be implemented as a simple `set -x` to turn on tracing at a given point of a script and `set +x` to turn it off.

If you definitely wish to implement it as a one line flag, I would take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) and configure `-x` flag through DEBUG trap.